# REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract a substring from Vertical SQL

Tags: sql, regex, pcre, vertica

I am trying to run the below query to get a substring from a string but it gives wrong result. I am not sure how to use the regex since the regex I am using works well with PCRE.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
  'Wireless-Interface-APName-ndehqb-a3g4-a10-slotId-1'
, '.*\-APName\-(.*)\-slotId.*'
)
```

I am expecting to get `ndehqb-a3g4-a10` in this case but it prints the original string itself. The ask is to get the substring that matches anything between `-APName-` and `-slotId-`

### UPDATE

Since Vertica's regular expression functions use PCRE, tagging this with other relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not trying to get the whole pattern (that would be the whole input string), but the first subexpression that you capture in round parentheses.

This makes the call a bit more complex - and I always have to look it up in the docu, as I never seem to be able to memorise all possible parameters and their order.

Here is how I would call it, with commented parameters:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    'Wireless-Interface-APName-ndehqb-a3g4-a10-slotId-1' -- in string
  , '.*\-APName\-(.*)\-slotId.*'                         -- pattern
  , 1                                                    -- search start position
  , 1                                                    -- occurrence
  , ''                                                   -- modifier
  , 1                                                    -- captured subexp number
  ) AS captured_subexp
;
-- out  captured_subexp 
-- out -----------------
-- out  ndehqb-a3g4-a10
```

Comment: that worked. I misread the documentation. I thought that not supplying any optional arguments will exhibit the default behavior. Thanks for replying.